# Akka input stream handling

Tags: java, ssh, playframework, akka, inputstream

I am building a system on akka/play framework with java. I need to build an actor who does a SSH connection to an external system & maintain the session for the span of user interaction..

I found Java JCraft/JSch library that supports java SSH connectivity

1. Is there a way to wrap JSch input stream as a event driven input stream, hence when data arrives a onmessage(data) event is fired.
2. Other option I have is to have a worker thread read/wait data from the stream living inside the scope of the actor, is this a good pattern, I am worried a worker thread would reduce scalability significantly
3. I found akka socket support but not specifically SSH, is there already such a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsch channels support writing to a given OutputStream

```
channel.setOutputStream(stream)
```

As the solution what I did was to write a custom OutputStream that on `write(buffer)` pass the buffer contents to a given actor via
actorRef.tell(buffer, ActorRef.noSender());

thus eliminating the need for a external thread.

Comment: You should make sure, given the multithreaded nature of actors, that your passing of the buffer is actually safe. Maybe you should pass a copy of the buffer, and not the buffer itself (that is : what if your `actorRef` gets your message at the same time JSCH is writing to the outputstream ? Are you guaranteed that the *same* buffer is not reused ?).